# SQL Server 2019 Enterprise - ##MS_SchemaSigningCertificate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, master-system-database

I have accidentally deleted my ##MS_SchemaSigningCertificate from my master DB.  What impact does this have and what should I do to get it back?

Comment: Got any backups?

Comment: I never thought about restoring the master.  Thx!